# How can I get Android Studio to import Classes at the top of my class instead of inline?

Tags: android-studio

Hopefully the title makes sense; As you can see from the image below, when I type `Channel` Android Studio auto-completes `WifiP2pManager.Channel` inline instead of putting `import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;` at the top of the class. 
I suspect it's doing it this way because I've already imported `WifiP2pManager`.
Is there a way to change this so it adds the import at the top of the class instead?

[image: Channel import]

Answer (score 0):

You can use android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.* instead of android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager  .It will be loaded all methods in this wifip2Manager.

Answer (score 0):

To fix that you need to go to File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Java
And click the Imports tab.

Now just check the same settings as the image below or just select Default on top in the drop down Scheme.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REgl2.jpg)

Then you can just make sure you have the regular Auto Import setting so android studio Auto imports your classes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOdjc.jpg)